# Ansible - Replace the host part of an ipv4 address

Tags: ipv4, ansible

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False

  vars_prompt:
    - name: ServerIP
      prompt: Enter the ServerIP to replace
      private: False
      default: "11.11.4.10"

  vars:
    Y: '126'

  pre_tasks:
    - name: Set some facts
      set_fact:
        ServerIP1: "{{ServerIP}}"

    - name: Save ServerIP in a register
      shell: echo {{ServerIP1}}
      register: resultip
```

Note: I know I can split the host portion of the Ip using the following code:

```
- name: show the last octet of the ServerIP
  debug: msg={{resultip.stdout.split('.')[3]}}
```

What I want:

```
- name: Replace the last octet of the ServerIP with a variable var
  # How can I do this ?
```

I want to store/display:

**x.x.x.{{ Y }}**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replace the last octet of `ServerIP` with the value
of `Y` the following should work for you:

```
set_fact:
  NewIP: "{{ ServerIP.split('.')[0] }}.{{ ServerIP.split('.')[1] }}.{{ ServerIP.split('.')[2] }}.{{ Y }}"
```

Comment: The expression can be shortened: `{{ ServerIP.split('.')[:3] | join('.') }}.{{Y}}`